# Allow negative/positive numbers but not letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to disable letters in my textbox, that's why I used this expression:

```
/^[0-9]*$/
```

The problem is that I want to allow negative numbers too, 
 and this expression does'nt enable me to use minus sign.(-)..
What shuold I do?

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with following regexp:

```
/^-?[0-9]*$/
```

Comment: Probably `+` rather than `*` though, eh? E.g., `/^-?[0-9]+$/`. We don't want to match "-".

Comment: Nope - this regexp is applicable for textarea. User is typing some input data, so he will first type `-` and then `-1`.. `-13`...

Comment: `@hsz`: It depends when and how you use it, I guess. If you're using it for validation after the fact, use `+` because "-" should be invalid. If you're using it for on-the-fly, use `*`. @ParPar: Proof of hsz's regexp: http://jsbin.com/utuyuq (that's the `+` version, change if required).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure. It should be clarified by `@ParPar`

Comment: @Michael [makes a good point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996195/allow-negative-positive-numbers-but-not-letters/7996248#7996248) about allowing a space.

Comment: @ParPar letters ? It allows only `-` and digits.

Comment: @hsz Sorry, you're right. I was a little confused cause I used it within a condition: <code>if($("#MyField").val().match(/^-?[0-9]*$/ )){alert("must be a number!");}<code>  Do you know how I can ask if not match? Is there anything like that..?

Comment: Simply ad `!` to negate expression in `if`.

Comment: I just added ! in the "if" and it all came on his place in peace!</br>Thank you hsz!

Answer (score 5):

More correctly: `/^(?:- *)?[0-9]+$/`

Since it is usually allowed to have one or more spaces between the minus sign and the digits. Also, you **must** have at least one digit to have a valid number.

Comment: However in this example `-` is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide you want to match all kinds of numbers, including floating point, [this is a good read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).  If you just want to match simple integers with an optional "minus" sign, then [go with hsz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996195/allow-negative-positive-numbers-but-not-letters/7996219#7996219), though I might change the `*` to a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function of JavaScript.

Here is a code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    numbersPlusMinus();
});


function numbersPlusMinus() {

    var inputPrev = "";

    $(".toNumberPlusMinus").change(function () {

        if (isNaN($(this).val())) {

            $(this).val(inputPrev);

        } else {

            inputPrev = $(this).val();
        }
    });
}
```